# My application will not automatically start with windows - what is wrong here?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, admin, startup

I am using the following code to manage the automatic startup of my application. The application has been set up to require admin privileges, and indeed, does ask for them.

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
if (checkRunOnStartup.Checked)
{
    rkApp.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
}
else
{
    rkApp.DeleteValue("MyApp", false);
}
```

This does not work on any system I have tested on, except from my development machine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked that the registry key is actually created on any system other than your development machine? If it is there, are there any logs in Windows Event Log? If it isn't there, does the user which executes your software have enough rights to alter the registry?

Comment: What is not working exactly ? Do you get an exception ? Is the key not added in registry ? Is it added but the program doesn't not run on startup ?

Comment: The registry key appears to have been created - it even shows in MSCONFIG.

Comment: Are there any entries in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: There are no entries from or about my application in the event viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing reg keys you could create/delete a shortcut to your app in the windows startup folder.  Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup will return you that path.  If you dead set on the reg key option here is a snippet of code per [DotnetThoughts](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/run-the-application-at-windows-startup/) .  Seems the main difference is he dropped the .ToString().

```
private void RegisterInStartup(bool isChecked)
{
   RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
   if (isChecked)
   {
       registryKey.SetValue("ApplicationName", Application.ExecutablePath);
   }
   else
   {
     registryKey.DeleteValue("ApplicationName");
   }
}
```

Comment: I will see about setting up the shortcut instead. My logic for using the registry was based off Microsoft Office using the registry - if they use it, so should I.

Comment: Turns out creating shortcuts in .Net is surprisingly difficult and clearly non-standard. I'd like to be able to use the registry ideally. .ToString() doesn't change anything, I'm afraid

Comment: No doubt I have used the startup folder a number of times for scripts and things of that nature and it works well.  I am with you on the Microsoft thing, if its what they claim they use it should work.

Comment: The problem with using the shortcut method is that it requires use of Interop - clearly not standard.

Comment: It is unfortunate that I have had to go the shortcut route.

Comment: Well shucks, I would like a more standard approach as well but sometimes you have to role with what works.